# How can I control iTunes remotely

Tags: windows, audio, itunes, remote-access, remote-control

I have a desktop with a large music library connected to a high quality stereo and I'd like to be able to control which songs are playing, and in an ideal world, make playlists, using a laptop.

Essentially, I want the iTunes Remote app, which I have installed on my iPhone, to work from a laptop as well.

Desktop: Windows 7
Laptops: Windows Vista/XP

Note: I am not asking how to stream music from my desktop to my laptop.

Comment: I'm happy to hear why my question was downvoted.  I realize that a similar question was asked 2+ years ago, but the "answer" does not work for Windows so I think it deserves more attention.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx), a free app which works both on a PC and mobile devices such as the iPhone and gives you remove access to any device/PC via the Internet.

It is not a direct iTunes-remote-control, however, you can do almost anything you normally do on your PC (including operate iTunes) from a remote device, i.e. your iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though this is a rather inconvenient solution.  For one, I'd have to stop using the desktop while the laptop-user took control of the mouse and screen to DJ.

Comment: Yep, this is absolutely true. I would be glad to know if there is a more intelligent solution to this; but it would certainly (and unfortunately) not include Apple software...

Answer (score 1):

Realise this is an old thread, however, there is an app in the Windows Store called "rtRemote for iTunes" - this is a Windows 8 /RT remote control for iTunes that is very similar to the Apple Remote app but you can run it on a laptop or a tablet.  Whilst this is for Windows 8 (not Windows 7 as per your specific scenario), as the thread is almost a year old, you may have upgraded by now!

See http://www.bizmodeller.com/rtRemote

Comment: Is it the only solution for Windows? Is there any Win32 application for this, not a Metro app? I have searched Google, but so far I only only found that app and this question page. Since there is Metro and Android apps for this, the protocol must have been publicly known, so a Win32 version is not impossible...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a java base app from google:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/tunesremote-se/wikis
Seems to work.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.